# using jquery on child page

Tags: jquery, colorbox

if i load('mypage.htm') into `<div id="placeMyContentHere">`

do i need to put JQuery in  "mypage.htm". I'm using color box ( of light box ike)  on my child page. If i add jquery.js & colorbox.js into mypage.htm it works. Though i can't helping thinking there is better way.

Here is how i normally call colorbox

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$("a[rel='example1']").colorbox();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `load`'s callback function to re-initialise colorbox, there is no need for a `$(document).ready(...` in the content you are injecting into your `div`, e.g.:

```
$("#placeMyContentHere").load('mypage.htm', function() {
    $("a[rel='example1']").colorbox();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You don need to include jquery and colorbox in child page. You are changing the DOM object therefore use jquery live

```
$("a[rel='example1']").live(function(){
   $(this).colorbox();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you should only include your javascript libraries (jQuery and plugins) once; on the main page.